# Unable to change "MaxSpareServers"?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf

I wanted to increase the `MaxSpareServers`.

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
MaxSpareServers      20
</IfModule>
```

However, I get the below error while testing.

```
[root@server_1 conf.modules.d]# httpd -t
AH00526: Syntax error on line 26 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf:
Invalid command 'MaxSpareServers', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I then verified a few points such as the MPM selection

```
[root@server_1 worker]# httpd -V | grep -i mpm
Server MPM:     worker
```

```
[root@server_1 worker]# httpd -M | grep -i mpm
 mpm_worker_module (shared)
```

Weirdly, when I checked the loaded modules, I couldn't find `worker.c`

```
[root@server_1 worker]# httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  http_core.c
```

Could this be the reason why am not able to change server configuration `MaxSpareServers`? If so, how do I fix this?

Please see below the version details

```
[root@server_1 worker]# yum info httpd
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, fastestmirror, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
Name        : httpd
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.4.52
Release     : 1.codeit.el7
Size        : 4.3 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : CodeIT
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
URL         : https://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and extensible
            : web server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running `mpm_worker_module` but `MaxSpareServers` is defined for `mpm_prefork_module`.